# Fit Probabilities in Multi-Label Classifiers

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

I'd like to use scikit-learn to classifiy into multiple categories, as described here [use scikit-learn to classify into multiple categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526579/use-scikit-learn-to-classify-into-multiple-categories),
but instead of returning the labels the classifier computes, I'd like to return probability of membership. Is this possible with scikit-learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, OneVsRestClassifier does not implement predict_proba yet. Please file a bug report or send us a pull-request (it should just be a matter of calling predict_proba on the n_classes underlying estimators and feeding the n_samples * n_classes matrix with the results).

Comment: I'll have a closer look at OneVsRestClassifier source and see if I can't manage a pull request. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you also need to normalize so that probabilities sum to 1.

Comment: Actually, in the multilabel case, since the events are not disjoint, isn't it true that probabilities **do not** need to sum to one? E.g. if the event that `sample_1` has `label_1` occurs with probability 90%, that doesn't tell us anything about probabilities that sample_1 has labels `label_2`, `label_3` or `label_4`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Btw, you problem could easily be solved by training one separate classifier per class. Of course supporting that out-of-the-box in OneVsRestClassifier is better ;)