# Using scikit-learn classifier inside nltk, multiclass case

Tags: python, nltk, scikit-learn

Classification of text documents is a [simple task with scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526579/use-scikit-learn-to-classify-into-multiple-categories) but there isn't a clean support of that in NLTK, also there are samples for doing that in hard way like [this](https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer/blob/master/nltk_trainer/classification/multi.py#L79). I want to preprocess with NLTK and classify with sckit-learn and I found SklearnClassifier in NLTK, but there is a little problem.

In scikit-learn everything is OK:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier

X_train = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]
y_train = [('first',), ('second',), ('first', 'second')]

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB())
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print clf.classes_
```

The result is `['first' 'second']` and it's my expectation. But when I try to use same code in NLTK:

```
from nltk.classify import SklearnClassifier

X_train = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 1}, {'c': 1}]
y_train = [('first',), ('second',), ('first', 'second')]
clf = SklearnClassifier(OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB()))
clf.train(zip(X_train, y_train))
print clf.labels()
```

The result is `[('first',), ('second',), ('first', 'second')]` and it isn't the proper one. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The NLTK wrapper for scikit-learn doesn't know about multilabel classification, and it shouldn't because it doesn't implement [`MultiClassifierI`](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#nltk.classify.api.MultiClassifierI). Implementing that would require a separate class.

You can either implement the missing functionality, or use scikit-learn without the wrapper. Newer versions of scikit-learn have a `DictVectorizer` that accepts roughly the same inputs that the NLTK wrapper accepts:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

X_train_raw = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 1}, {'c': 1}]
y_train = [('first',), ('second',), ('first', 'second')]

v = DictVectorizer()
X_train = v.fit_transform(X_train_raw)

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB())
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You can then use `X_test = v.transform(X_test_raw)` to transform test samples to matrices. A `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` makes this easier by tying a vectorizer and a classifier together in a single object.

**Disclaimer**: according to the [FAQ](/faq), I should disclose my affiliation. I wrote both `DictVectorizer` and the NLTK wrapper for scikit-learn.