# Classify text into multiple categories from scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a text like,

```
"India, officially the Republic of India is a country in South Asia."
```

I need it to be able to give me,

```
Country: India
Region: South Asia
```

Whatever I found on scikit's documentation, it was able to classify it into one category, for example I could train this on two classifier to check whether a country is present or region is present, but I want it to tell me which feature it is picking up, bit like NLTK's most informative features, for each classification.
How do I do this?

Comment: what algorithm are you using to train classifiers?

Comment: @alivar I'm thinking of using SVM

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526579/use-scikit-learn-to-classify-into-multiple-categories) You can also check multilabel classification from [sckit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multilabel.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-multilabel-py) in particular the [OneVsRest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier) classiffier, I think this is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SVM [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/39243/53512) at cross validated may get you started. The idea is to interpret the classification weights, but that is not trivial.

Personally, I prefer to use a [`RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forests-of-randomized-trees), which has feature ranking built in. It's exposed by the `feature_importances_` attribute. There is even [an example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html) at the scikit-learn documentation.