# Prepare a training dataset for multilabel classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification

I just followed the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10527953/3478591) (with minor modifications for sklearn 0.17). In that example, data are just lists or numpy arrays. Now I want to prepare a toy training dataset on the disk, and use `datasets.load_files` to load it for multilabel classification. However, simply following the [`load_files`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html) convention, and then copying the same file into multiple folders, doesn't produce a list of lists (aka. label sets) for `dataset.target`.

So what is the correct way to prepare a dataset for multilabel classification?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `load_files` supports multilabel classes, to be honest I've never used scikit learn to load data, I always do my initial data load and preprocessing using pandas. One option for your case would be to store your data as csv, serializing your labels as pipe-delimited lists

For example your file `data.csv` might be

```
recipe_name,classes
'stir fried broccoli',chinese|vegetarian
'kung po chicken',chinese|meat
'sauerkraut salad',vegetarian|polish
```

And you would load it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X_train = df.recipe_name
y_train = df.classes.str.split('|')
```

Comment: Thanks @maxymoo, this is a good point. I crawl and store multiple files, so perhaps I will just name each document using a list of labels, no more folder structures, and write a function to parse the file names and read the contents...

Comment: if you are crawling, you might want to consider using a database like mongodb or postgres, you might be glad for it in the long run rather than having a bunch of files floating around. also you can do some of the preprossing on the database which can be handy.