# Classify multiple categories with scikit - using a threshold

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was reading this post: [use scikit-learn to classify into multiple categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526579/use-scikit-learn-to-classify-into-multiple-categories) which kind of does what I am looking for.

For this exercise I use same dataset:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing

X_train = np.array(["new york is a hell of a town",
                "new york was originally dutch",
                "the big apple is great",
                "new york is also called the big apple",
                "nyc is nice",
                "people abbreviate new york city as nyc",
                "the capital of great britain is london",
                "london is in the uk",
                "london is in england",
                "london is in great britain",
                "it rains a lot in london",
                "london hosts the british museum",
                "new york is great and so is london",
                "i like london better than new york"])
y_train_text = [["new york"],["new york"],["new york"],["new york"],["new york"],
            ["new york"],["london"],["london"],["london"],["london"],
            ["london"],["london"],["new york","london"],["new york","london"]]

X_test = np.array(['nice day in nyc',
               'welcome to london',
               'london is rainy',
               'it is raining in britian',
               'it is raining in britian and the big apple',
               'it is raining in britian and nyc',
               'hello welcome to new york. enjoy it here and london too'])
target_names = ['New York', 'London']
```

And process the data in the same way:

```
lb = preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()
Y = lb.fit_transform(y_train_text)

classifier = Pipeline([
 ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
 ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))])

classifier.fit(X_train, Y)
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
all_labels = lb.inverse_transform(predicted)

for item, labels in zip(X_test, all_labels):
 print '%s => %s' % (item, ', '.join(labels))
```

This all works and gives me what I am looking for. However I would really like to set a manual threshold to determine what tags will appear. So if for example I set the threshold to be 70% then I would like all tags with higher than 70% probability to appear as tags. If (for example) London has a 69% probability it should not shown.

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Comment: Questions about how to use software are off topic here. This question should be on topic on [SO]; if you wait, we will try to migrate it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is `predict_proba` ([doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.predict_proba)).

`predict` give you the class predicted by your classifier, for each sample. On the other hand `predict_proba` will give you the probabilities associated with each class, for each sample.

I suggest a code below, note that I didn't run it so it may contain trivial errors, the point is to give an example of how you could do it. It may have better solution somehow

```
# Get a [n_samples, n_classes] array with each class probabilites for each samples
predicted_proba = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)

labels = []
threshold = 0.7

# Iterating over results
for probs in predicted_proba:
   labels.append([])

   # Iterating over class probabilities
   for i in range(len(probs)):
      if probs[i] >= threshold:
         # We add the class
         labels[-1].append(i)
```

Hope it helps

`pltrdy`

Comment: But how to use these binary value of label to get actual text label?